# Different o/p - Lists

Tags: python, list

I tried to make a program that gives me errors, but actually I can't put inputs.

What I want to do is something that receives a **list of marks**, from 0 to 20, and a minimum passing grade `min_grade`, and returns the number of entries in the grades list with a value greater than or equal to `min_grade`, and another function with the media_approved:

***The output I want will be something like this:***

```
approved([11.2, 13.5, 7.6, 4.4, 12.2, 12.1, 18.2, 9.4, 18.3, 12.33], 9.5)
6
approved([7.5, 3.3, 6.6, 6.4], 9.5)
0
average_passed([11.2, 13.5, 7.6, 4.4, 12.2, 12.1, 18.2, 9.4, 18.3, 12.3], 9.5)
13.9166
average_passed([7.5, 3.3, 6.6, 6.4], 9.5)
0
```

The program I made is wrong, because it only calculates the average, it is badly programmed and does not have a part of what I said earlier.

Then goes the code:

```py
def calc_average(s, scores):
    scores = []


c = float(input())


def average(grades, c):
    return sum(scores) / len(scores)


s = [11.2, 13.5, 7.6, 4.4, 12.2, 12.1, 18.2, 9.4, 18.3, 12.3]
print(average(s))
```

Can anyone help me, to change my code so that it is the same as the output I put earlier?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please run your code through line by line on paper, work out what you expect it to do on each line of code.  you will see that you use a variable' scores' that you never assign anything to, among other things.

Comment: `len([g for g in grades if g >= min_grade])` ?

Comment: @OlvinRoght If you're building a list, take its `len`. `sum(1 for ..)` makes sense if your're using a generator expression.

Comment: @fpb_i, you already got [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70802960/10824407) which does exactly the same with one-liner from [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70802841/10824407#comment125168716_70802841). If you are not familiar with list comprehensions, code from answer should be more explicit. If you don't understand neither my code nor code from answer, I strongly recommend you to spend an evening reading official [Python Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/).

Comment: From all your questions in your profile, it appears you're using Stackoverflow to get your Python assignments done by others. Some of your questions are very basic that you can answer by learning Python than by asking others to solve your quizzes.

Comment: Sorry, but I just wanted you to help me correct my mistakes. I'm new to Python and I want to learn Python, so it's normal for you to be easy, but for me it's difficult. I try to do but the code has errors. It is normal to ask other users for help, as I know that programming is not learned overnight. Don't make me give up because I'm ashamed of not being able to program well. I hope I can in the future, but at this stage, it's still very early. I started programming Python now, so it's normal that it's still difficult for me.
I also appreciate the help everyone has given me. Regards!

Comment: Olvin Roght and Krishnakanth Allika I understood your code by searching a lot for the definitions of it. Thank you for all your understanding and help!

Comment: @fpb_i, I posted an answer that should solve your problem, but please spend time understanding the code. If you're a beginner, go through Python list comprehension.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to calculate number of values greater than the given i/p. One of the potential solutions is:

```
def fn(input_list, target):
    approved = []

    for i in range(len(input_list)):
        if input_list[i] >= target:
            approved.append(input_list[i])

    return len(approved)
```

This surely solves the first problem. I am not sure what media_approved means. Could you please elaborate on the same.
Thank you, I hope this helps.

Comment: Iterating over indexes is not a common way in python, `for score in input_list` is.

Answer (score 0):

```
def averaged_passed(s, c):
  scores = []
  for i in range(len(s)):
     if(s[i]>=c):
       scores.append(s[i])
  try:
    return sum(scores)/len(scores)
  except:
    return('No one passed')
      
def approved(s, c):
  count =0
  for i in range(len(s)):
     if(s[i]>=c):
       count=count+1
  return count
c = float(input())


s = [7, 3, 6, 6]
print(pass(s,c))
```

Comment: Why are you iterating over indexes? Why are you using `try .. except` instead of just check length of `scores`?

Comment: try..except is faster than if..else if the exceptions arises. But you pointed out correctly, it can be used.

Comment: Thank you for your willingness to help me ehsan!

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you want two functions:

1. `approved` to return the number of marks that are greater than or equal to `min_grade`.
2. `average_passed` to return the average of all passed marks.

```
def approved(grades, min_grade):
    return len([grade for grade in grades if grade >= min_grade])

def average_passed(grades, min_grade):
    passed = [grade for grade in grades if grade >= min_grade]
    return sum(passed)/len(passed) if passed else 0
```

Output:

`approved([11.2, 13.5, 7.6, 4.4, 12.2, 12.1, 18.2, 9.4, 18.3, 12.33], 9.5)`
`7`

`approved([7.5, 3.3, 6.6, 6.4], 9.5)`
`0`

`average_passed([11.2, 13.5, 7.6, 4.4, 12.2, 12.1, 18.2, 9.4, 18.3, 12.3], 9.5)`
`13.971428571428572`

`average_passed([7.5, 3.3, 6.6, 6.4], 9.5)`
`0`

If you are beginner, you might want to refer to Python list comprehension and condensed if-else statement to understand the code.

For example,
`return sum(passed)/len(passed) if passed else 0` is equivalent to

```
if passed: # returns True if the list is not empty, else False
    return sum(passed)/len(passed) # calc average if list is not empty
else:
    return 0 # return zero if list is empty
```